# Sort Array with reference of AnyCollection<(label: Optional<String>, value: Any)> in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, mirror

I'm getting variables of Struct as `[Key:Value]` inside an array by using `Mirror`. Mirror returns variables in a sorted order. However, after they are set on array, sort spoils. How can I protect the sort? I try to sort array after set with reference of `Mirror.children` but can't figure out.

for loop inside function returns a correct and sorted value. Problem is after they are set on `result[property] = value`, sort spoils. How can I protect the sort?

```
extension Loopable {

    func allProperties() throws -> [String: Any] {

        var result: [String: Any] = [:]

        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

        // Optional check to make sure we're iterating over a struct or class
        guard let style = mirror.displayStyle, style == .struct || style == .class else {
            throw NSError()
        }

        for (property, value) in mirror.children {
            guard let property = property else {
                continue
            }
            result[property] = value
        }
        //let sorted = result.sorted{ mirror.children.index(of: $0.key)! < mirror.children.index(of: $1.key)! } TRYING THIS
        return result
    }

}
```

Comment: A dictionary is an *unordered* collection.

Comment: So how should I do it?

Comment: If the order is important then you cannot represent it as a dictionary. You can use an array of key/value pairs instead.

Comment: Does my result isn't a dictionary?

Comment: Please check the results for https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+dictionary+order . A dictionary does not preserve order.

Comment: I don't think this as a duplicate question. Why It is marked as duplicate